# Storing random integer

Tags: python, random, numbers

I have recently started to program in Python. Now im working on a number guessing game. I have a proplem with understanding how does storing a random number works.I have looked around here, found some answer but couldnt make it work. The code works fine, but my answer (random number) is always different, so its imposible to guess it. 
If anybody could help me or improve my code i would be glad.
Here is the part of that code where i have it:

```
   def game(self):
    import random
    answer = random.randint(0, 1000)
    guess = int(input("Your tip is:"))
    while True:
        if guess < answer:
            print ("Your tip is lower, than the answer! Try again.")
            self.game()
        elif guess > answer:
            print ("Your tip is bigger than the answer! Try again.")
            self.game()
        elif guess == answer:
            print ("Good job! You have found the answer!")
            self.replay()
```

Comment: Don't call `self.game()` inside the `while` loop, just let it loop. And move the `guess =` line into the loop.

Comment: Move the line that contains `input` at the begining of the `while` loop, and instead of calling `self.game()` use `continue`, and a `break` after `self.replay()`.

Comment: And please don't put `import` statements inside functions (unless you're certain that you _need_ to do that). Put them at the start of the script, where they belong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are calling `self.game()` inside each if statement, which brings the execution flow back to the start of the function and generates a new number each time with `answer = random.randint(0, 1000)`.

So simply remove `self.game()` and let the function reach the end:

```
import random

def game(self):
    answer = random.randint(0, 1000)
    while True:
        guess = int(input("Your tip is:"))
        if guess < answer:
            print ("Your tip is lower, than the answer! Try again.")
        elif guess > answer:
            print ("Your tip is bigger than the answer! Try again.")
        elif guess == answer:
            print ("Good job! You have found the answer!")
            self.replay()
            break
```

EDIT 1:

You should also move the line where the user inputs his guess inside the `while` loop so that the user can guess until he gets the correct answer. I also added `break` statements to exit the loop when he gets the correct answer instead of only print statements. You can read more about `break` [here](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/break.html) (answer code above now updated)

EDIT 2:

Another small detail since you're new to Python: you should place all your import statements at the top of your python module, it's python coding guidelines that you should follow to make your code more clear. You can read more [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)